# How do I use psql "\copy" in Python?

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, copy, psycopg2, psql

I'm trying to import a csv-file into a psql database. After reading about the difference between `COPY` and `\copy` I get this error when executing my script.

Here's my code cutting:

```
try:

   csv_data = os.path.realpath('test.csv')

   con = psycopg2.connect(database = 'db01', user = 'postgres')
   cur = con.cursor()

   cur.execute("\copy stamm_data from '%s' DELIMITER ';' csv header" % csv_data)

   con.commit()
```

And here's the error:

```
Error: syntax error at or near "\"
LINE 1: \copy stamm_data from '/home/jw/dev/test.csv' delimiter ';' ...
    ^
```

When using `COPY` I get:

```
Error: could not open file "/home/jw/dev/test.csv" for reading: Permission denied
```

Though the psql user 'postgres' is a superuser and the ubuntu user to run the script has reading permissions on the test.csv file.

Any ideas?

Comment: `\copy` is for the psql command line tool. python has [copy_from](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_from) and copy_to.

Comment: thank you! I didn't know that psycopg2 provides a function like that. one more question: when I use `copy_from` I can't ignore the csv-header like in the psql command, I'm right? The best solution for me is to cut the first line (header) from the csv-data and then import the file with `copy_from`?

Comment: Yes, either that or see `copy_expert` instead of `copy_from`

Comment: I've read about `copy_expert`.. with `copy_expert` you need to bee a superuser and that's what I want to prevent.. btw. whats the difference between `copy_expert` and psycopg2.execute("COPY..")?

Comment: Not exactly. Superuser is needed with server-side COPY FROM only if the source is a file. It's **not needed** if the source is  `FROM STDIN`, which means the client is streaming contents to the server as opposed to asking it to open a file on its own filesystem with its own permissions.

Comment: `psycopg2.execute("COPY..")` would only work with a file on the server filesystem, because if doing  `psycopg2.execute("COPY tablename FROM STDIN...")`, how would you feed it with the input data? That's what `copy_expert` is for.

Comment: @jwi you can ignore the first line of a csv using `copy_from` by adding `next(f)` after the `open('file.csv', 'r') as f:` line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here we go.. The solution with `copy_from` works fine - I remove the header from the csv-file and import that file with `copy_from`.

But now I'm running into the following error:

```
Error: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, foo01, ACE001, 3).
```

My table has the following columns:

```
ID, hotelcode, hotelname, stars
```

ID is my PK, so I cant remove the NOT NULL modifier. How do I import the ID's for each line? Or how do I say Postgres to fill the column ID with the value 'DEFAULT', so that the database generates the id's by itself?

Comment: Found the solution by myself: only change the type from the column ID in my table from INT to SERIAL - works fine. cheers!

Comment: if there was a default set int should have worked. also it would be nice to see the working code.